# Can I use application launcher icon for menu icons and action bar icons?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to add an icon to a menu in the navigation drawer, and I created the icon using image assets by the type of launcher icons(adaptive and legacy) then when I assign its name to the menu item it shows just blank but when I write the icons foreground layer names it works, why? because when I choose the icon type action bar and tab icons then it works with the icon's name. I hope you could understand the question.

Comment: `I hope you could understand the question.` unortunately no. Show the code how it works and how it does not.

Comment: `when when I assign its name to the menu item it shows just blank` you can't do this without the code, therefore there is the code, and that is the code you need to show

Comment: Nice copy of the previous comment. Do you want one more copy of my?

Comment: ok, looks like it does not make sense to continue, as you ignore everything.